# Best Way to Host a Rails App on a Windows Server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, deployment

I have a simple rails app that I need to deploy on a Window Server 2008 R2 server. I have looked around but have not found much on the topic. What are some simple / best ways of accomplishing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can use Capistrano to deploy on windows. Otherwise you may want to have a look at [kwatee](http://www.kwatee.net) (self-promotion). I haven't looked at deploying Rails app yet since Capistrano is the tool of choice there but kwatee is a free tool that can deploy pretty much anything from stand-alone applications, web applications on any platform, including windows.